# Git colors - branch description text

Tags: git

It's straightforward to change the colors that the git shell uses. For example, if I want to change the color of untracked files from red to 'red bold', I type:

```
git config --local --replace color.status.untracked "red bold"
```

The trick is to know the setting name for each display element.

The command prompt always tells you the current branch you're on, and a summary of the status information. The color of the summary is red. I want it to be a different color.

What is the setting name that represents the summary text element?

[image]

Comment: Something else is controlling that.  I know on *nix systems (OS X, Linux), that's controlled exclusively by your `__GIT_PS1` setting/configuration, so nothing that Git would be able to touch would generally govern it.  Not sure what it is on Windows though, but I doubt that it's a configuration that Git exclusively would be handling.

Comment: It's [posh-git](https://github.com/dahlbyk/posh-git)

Answer (score 1):

It appears that the prompt colors are set via a different mechanism than the outputs colors.

If, on the powershell commandline, you type

```
$global:GitPromptSettings
```

You will see the settings relating to how the git prompt displays. Some of these values:

```
BranchBehindForegroundColor            : Red
RepositoriesInWhichToDisableFileStatus : {}
BranchForegroundColor                  : Cyan
BranchBehindAndAheadBackgroundColor    : Black
BranchBehindAndAheadForegroundColor    : Yellow
BeforeText                             :  [
WorkingBackgroundColor                 : Black
WorkingForegroundColor                 : DarkRed
EnableWindowTitle                      : posh~git ~ 
BranchBehindBackgroundColor            : Black
BeforeIndexText                        : 
ShowStatusWhenZero                     : True
DelimText                              :  |
BeforeBackgroundColor                  : Black
UntrackedForegroundColor               : DarkRed
IndexForegroundColor                   : DarkGreen
```

The setting I needed to change here was `WorkingForegroundColor`

I could test the results of changing this value straight away by typing:

```
$global:GitPromptSettings.WorkingForegroundColor = [ConsoleColor]::Green
```

---

Useful blog entries on this subject:

- [this blog entry](http://sedodream.com/2012/05/05/GitCustomizingColorsForWindowsIncludingPoshgit.aspx) by Sayed Ibrahim Hashimi.
- [This entry](http://davidzych.com/coloring-your-posh-git-output/) by David Zych